# Is there a option to store Stack Overflow posts?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

My doubt is on using Stack Overflow. Is there a way I can save a Stack Overflow post which I like on my profile page, so that they can be my future references?

I mean a function similar to Facebook likes or Pintrest pins.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the star below the question score and it will be added to your favorites in your profile.